# Pushing a local branch up to GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-push

I have Git configured so that when I run `git push`, it pushes changes to my GitHub repo. Until now I have only had a master branch.

However, I have now created a local branch and committed to it using:

```
git checkout -b my_new_branch
git commit
```

What I would like to do now is push my changes on this branch to GitHub. Do I just do a git push?

When I first set it up I did run:

```
git config push.default current
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? With `push.default` set that way, yes, `git push` will push the current branch to origin, which is your github repo, assuming you cloned from there. (You could specify a different remote with `branch.my_new_branch.remote` if you wanted.) So did you try this and have it not work?

Comment: If you want all your local branches to push to the same remote branch, be explicit:  git push origin HEAD:remote_branch

Answer (score 222):

I believe you're looking for `git push origin my_new_branch`, assuming your origin remote is configured to hit your github repository.

Comment: git push <remote> <branch>  as per https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-push

Comment: If you then want to work on this branch with other people and hence do git pull you'll want to set tracking information for your new branch:

`git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/my_new_branch my_new_branch`

Answer (score 9):

Depending on your local git settings, if you have a branch checked out that isn't the one you cloned or one that exists where you are trying to push, git will not push your local branch.

Here is the message it provides:

> warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value has changed in Git
>   2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message and maintain the traditional behavior, use:
>
> git config --global push.default matching
>
> To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:
>
> git config --global push.default simple
>
> When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
>   to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.
>
> Since Git 2.0, Git defaults to the more conservative 'simple'
>   behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
>   remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.
>
> See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further
>   information. (the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the
>   similar mode 'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older
>   versions of Git)
>
> fatal: The current branch `MyLocalBranch` has no upstream branch. To push the
>   current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
>
> ```
> git push --set-upstream origin MyLocalBranch
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are really lazy, you can [push all local branches](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---all) by simply using

```
git push --all
```

> **--all**
>
> Push all branches (i.e. refs under `refs/heads/`); cannot be used with
>   other `<refspec>`.

Answer (score -12):

If you've configured your git to push to your GitHub master repo, no matter in with branch you are, it will push to your GitHub master repo.

Bear in mind that, if many developers are working in the same repository, you could get a conflict.

Comment: I did run git config push.default current