# Commit gitignore first time after creating a new repo in github

Tags: git, github

I have created a new repo in Github and now I want to push only gitignore file. On next commit I would like to push the rest of the files.

Steps I did --

```
> git branch
* master
> git branch -r
> git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   .idea/inspectionProfiles/Project_Default.xml
    new file:   .idea/vcs.xml

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .gitignore
    modified:   .idea/workspace.xml
```

So I put `.idea/workspace.xml` in the gitignore along with `.idea` folder

```
> git add .gitignore
> git commit -m 'gitignore only'
```

My question is what would be the push command as there is no branch in remote repo.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**Update -1**

I tried with following -

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "git ignore only"
git push origin master
```

Now when I check remote github I can see all the files have been added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pushing a local branch up to GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752387/pushing-a-local-branch-up-to-github)

Comment: @Yousaf No I created my local repo first and then created the remote repo. Now I want to commit first time just the gitignore file only. Nothing else. Last time I tried it commited all the files.

Comment: @CodeCaster I am not pushing any new branch. What I want is to push gitignore file only to the remote. I don't think this has any relation with your possible duplicate link. I just added gitignore file and commited and on github I can see all the files alongwith .idea folder.

Comment: Well your github repo has a branch then.

Comment: Nope..I just showed git branch -r result.

Comment: 1. If it's a new remote repo then it doesn't matter if you add any single file or bunch of files or all it will commit everything 2. Something else which I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

The two files `Project_Default.xml` and `vcs.xml` were already in the "staged" status. Adding them to `.gitignore` will not impact the fact that in the next `git commit`, they will be integrated in the commit (as they are "staged").

As we can see in the [gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) : "Files already tracked by Git are not affected"

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.

Comment: You're welcome, can you then upvote my solution (or even accept it) ?

Answer (score 0):

So, to recap:

- You have created your repo locally and initialised it (?)
- You are on your local branch called master.
- There are no remote branches
- You have staged (git add)  `.idea/inspectionProfiles/Project_Default.xml` and `.idea/vcs.xml`
- You have also staged `.gitignore`
- You want to only push the `.gitignore`

Am I understanding this correctly? Then you would need to :

1. Unstage `.idea/inspectionProfiles/Project_Default.xml` and `.idea/vcs.xml` using

```sh
$ git reset .idea/inspectionProfiles/Project_Default.xml
$ git reset .idea/vcs.xml
```

2. Push the current local master to the remote repo (supposing it is called "origin" and also create a "master" branch there):

```sh
$ git push origin master
```

3. Set up the local master to keep track of the remote master:

```sh
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
```

---

As a side note you could do step 2 by specifying the remote branch name:

```sh
$ git push origin master:remotemaster
```

Comment: Actually on first commit to the remote repo(if there is no remote branch available) it would push all the files not a single file. Not sure if this is right or wrong?

Comment: It shouldn't matter if there is or not a remote branch. It will only push what you have committed. So anything that has not been through "git add" and then "git commit" will be left only on the local branch